# Show Auto Focus Rectangle AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, xcode, video, camera, avcapturesession

I am close to having this work, I have the apple sample code from here https://github.com/master-nevi/WWDC-2010/tree/master/AVCamDemo and am trying to use the parts I want and am very close but I can quite get it. When I tap I want to have the AVCaptureSession focus where tapped and show a rectangle. Here what I have:

```
- (void)drawFocusBoxAtPointOfInterest:(CGPoint)point
{
    NSDictionary *unanimatedActions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNull null], @"bounds",[NSNull null], @"frame",[NSNull null], @"position", nil];
   CALayer *focusBox = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    [focusBox setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 100, 100)];
    [focusBox setPosition:point];
    [focusBox setBorderWidth:3.f];
    [focusBox setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f green:0.f blue:1.f alpha:.8f] CGColor]];
    [focusBox setOpacity:0.f];
    [PreviewLayer addSublayer:focusBox];
    [ViewController addAdjustingAnimationToLayer:focusBox removeAnimation:YES];
}    
}
```

This is where PreviewLayer is `@property (retain) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *PreviewLayer;`

Then this is `addAdjustingAnimationToLayer:focusBox`

```
+ (void)addAdjustingAnimationToLayer:(CALayer *)layer removeAnimation:(BOOL)remove
{
if (remove) {
    [layer removeAnimationForKey:@"animateOpacity"];
}
if ([layer animationForKey:@"animateOpacity"] == nil) {
    [layer setHidden:NO];
    CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [opacityAnimation setDuration:.3f];
    [opacityAnimation setRepeatCount:1.f];
    [opacityAnimation setAutoreverses:YES];
    [opacityAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.f]];
    [opacityAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:.0f]];
    [layer addAnimation:opacityAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
}
}
```

And I call `drawFocus` when a tap is registered and I know that part is working and the function `drawFocus` is being called as well as `addAdjustingAnimation` are both successfully called, I just don't see the box appear on the screen?

If you are doing this in your app have another way to do it, that would also be greatly appreciated if you could share that code :)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The box is probably misplaced. Since you have asked the other way to do this is to add focus view as a subview to the preview like https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder does.